# When is replacing the prefix of an angled internal address a valid operation?

Tags: complex-dynamics, symbolic-dynamics

While working on an artwork exploring patterns in the Mandelbrot set fractal, I constructed an [angled internal address](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411238) by:

$$
1 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 2 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 3 \overset{1/10}\longrightarrow 28 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow \\
56 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 57 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 58 \overset{1/3}\longrightarrow \\
144 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 145 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 146 \overset{1/3}\longrightarrow \\ \cdots \\
p-2 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow  p-1 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow  p \overset{1/3}\longrightarrow \\ 
2p+28 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 2p+29 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 2p+30 \overset{1/3}\longrightarrow  \\\
\cdots \\
\cdots 1378
$$

I then replaced the prefix $1 
\overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 2 \overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 3 \overset{1/10}\longrightarrow 28$ (keeping the suffix the same) by other period 28 islands in the hairs around the period 3 island, with periodic external angles in binary of the form $.\overline{\{011,100\}^8 0111}_2$ (choose one of the set 8 times, and concatenate all the strings: thus there are 256 different rays).

Is it just a coincidence that all of these angled internal addresses are realizable in the Mandelbrot set?

(This procedure did not give the pleasing animation I had hoped for.)

Comment: Modifying the procedure turned out well and gave the middle section of this video: https://diode.zone/videos/watch/8db3dcf1-a61a-458d-b454-0acfc762826b